# Convert DirectoryEntry to PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I have C# code that's creating a `DirectoryEntry` object like so:

```
new DirectoryEntry("GC://DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com");
```

and then I can use the normal searching routines just fine. Now I want to convert this code to use the newer `PrincipalContext` methods from .NET 3.5.

I can't figure out what to pass the constructor though to make a connection. How do I convert the above string into something that works with `PrincipalContext`?

Comment: why do you want to convert is there any specific reasons

Comment: Why wouldn't I is the better question.  If I have to go in and revamp code, I like to bring it up to modern standards when possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pcontext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "GC://DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com");
```

Comment: it is possible to convert `PrincipalContext` to `DirectoryEntry` ?